# Сделать поле активным при выборе input

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы поле ввода input стало активно при выборе 4го input-radio, но почему-то не получается.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.aim')[3].oninput = (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.checked) {
    document.querySelector('#aim').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="aim" type="radio" class="form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="декларирование" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim" type="radio" class="form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="производственный контроль" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim" type="radio" class="form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="получение информации о фактическом качестве продукции" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim" type="radio" name="aim" class="aim" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>

  <input id="aim" type="text" class="form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="{{ old('aim') }}" autocomplete="aim" autofocus disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: поменяете местами поля, будет код потом переписывать? добавьте к нему id и по нему и обращайтесь. зы: индексация с 0

Comment: Что-то не понял. Что поменять местами и куда id добавить? У всех input есть id, по идее он должен быть одинаковый, потому что это всё в зависимости от выбора отправляется в один и тот же столбец в БД

Comment: @REGEDIT073, `id` должен быть для всех элементов обязательно разным. И для `input` в том числе, это поле name должно быть одинаковым, чтобы сообщить браузеру что кнопки из одной группы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.aim')[3].oninput = (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.checked) {
    document.querySelector('#aim-text').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="aim-1" type="radio" class="aim form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="декларирование" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim-2" type="radio" class="aim form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="производственный контроль" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim-3" type="radio" class="aim form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" value="получение информации о фактическом качестве продукции" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>
  <input id="aim-4" type="radio" name="aim" class="aim" autocomplete="aim" autofocus>

  <input id="aim-text" type="text" class="form-control @error('aim') is-invalid @enderror" name="aim" autocomplete="aim" autofocus disabled>
</div>
```